# Visual Studio C# Dropdown List If Statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an If statement for a dropdown list on visual studio. When selecting a value in the list I would like it to show on its own once selected, although all values in the list are being outputted. Below is the code I'm using:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declare Variables 
            String strFrance;
            String strPortugal;
            String strItaly;
            String strSpain;
            String strAmsterdam;
            String strPoland;

            //Assign Values 
            strFrance = "300";
            strPortugal = "350";
            strItaly = "400";
            strSpain = "400";
            strAmsterdam = "250";
            strPoland = "350";

            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "France") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of France is" + strFrance + "<br />");
            }

            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "Portugal") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of Portugal is" + strPortugal + "<br />");
            }

            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "Italy") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of Italy is" + strItaly + "<br />");
            }
            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "Spain") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of Spain is" + strSpain + "<br />");
            }
            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "Amsterdam") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of Amsterdam is" + strAmsterdam + "<br />");
            }
            if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "Poland") ;
            {
                Response.Write("The Price of Poland is" + strPoland + "<br />");
            }
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy it directly in the post, with the proper formating.

Answer (score 2):

remove the `;` after the `if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "...") ;`

Ie

```
 if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "France")
 {
   Response.Write("The Price of France is" + strFrance + "<br />");
 }
```

instead of

```
 if (lstPackages.SelectedItem.Text == "France") ;
 {
   Response.Write("The Price of France is" + strFrance + "<br />");
 }
```

If you hover over the `;` in Visual Stuido you will see a warning ..

BTW: You can assign a value directly at creation of a variable. Ie

```
string strFrance = "300";
```

Comment: Thank You! Although some locations are still not working correctly?

Comment: Well, this obviously applies for all other `if (...)` you have shown as well ..

Comment: All locations other than Italy and Poland are working correctly. These two locations do not show any value when processed?

Comment: Then you should check if you have some typo somewhere. Set a breakpoint in that line and check the value in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help very much appreciated!